# How to update data in SQL table without overwritting existing data

Tags: php, mysql

How can I update a value that already exists in SQL database table without overwriting existing data in the table.
Here is a code I have tried

```
public function updateSch()
    {
       // $query = "UPDATE tbl_school_data SET schoolA = ? WHERE schoolId = ?";
        $query = "UPDATE tbl_school_data SET schoolA = schoolA & ? WHERE schoolId = ?";
        $obj = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        
        $this->schoolA  = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->schoolA));
        $this->schoolId = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->schoolId));

        $obj->bind_param("ss", $this->schoolA, $this->schoolId);

        if ($obj->execute()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
```

but when I run this the data changes to **0** for reasons I really don't understand I have tried with the query commented out it but that just does the regular update i.e. overwrite existing data but I would really like to know how to add to the data without overwriting.

Comment: did you check your $this->schoolA and $this->schoolId if its return to 0?

Comment: Assuming your column is schoolA: `UPDATE tbl_school_data SET schoolA = ? WHERE schoolId = ?`  Your `bind_param` is likely also incorrect, `$obj->bind_param("si", $this->schoolA, $this->schoolId);`

Comment: What column are you trying to update?

Comment: so you want to append instead? of ovewrite the data?

Comment: @jerson yes append instead of overwrite

Comment: @bassxzero the column am trying to update is schoolA but i want to append to the data not overwrite

Comment: You should never use `htmlspecialchars` when storing values into the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [concat](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp)

```
 UPDATE tbl_school_data SET schoolA = concat(ifnull(schoolA,''),?) WHERE schoolId = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

When the data changes to 0, it is usually an indication that your structure has the data value type set as `INT`. If you try to input text (or any invalid formats, as a matter of fact), the value will set itself to 0.

Comment: the value is longtext not INT i can add text to it directly

Comment: ooh append! In this case, you can use a `SELECT` statement to retrieve the data then concatenate it with PHP, then use UPDATE to add it back in.

Comment: no, select is unnecessary you can pull your existing data from calling column name

Comment: @Jerson sorry found my mistake spelt concat as concact